# APC + PHP-FPM Memory fragmented even with apc.user_ttl = 0

Tags: php-fpm, alternative-php-cache

I'm running `5.3.9-1~dotdeb.3`, with `APC 3.1.9`.
APC cache gets totally fragmented after a 2hours of running. Isn't the  `apc.user_ttl = 0`  supposed to keep the files cached until APC is restarted - and prevent this much fragmentation? What am I doing wrong?

```
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 320M
apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.stat = 0
apc.user_ttl = 0
apc.num_files_hint = 1024
apc.mmap_file_mask = /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli = 0
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I've managed to bring down the fragmentation to 10% by setting pm.max_requests to a higher value (from 50 to 250). Although this does crash php processes more often (http 502, recv() upstream errors).

Answer (score 0):

Did you raised the kernel `shmmax` parameter to server 320M for shared memory as well?
By default it's around 8MB.

Put the following into `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.shmmax = 335544320
```

and execute

```
sysctl -p
```

as root.